# Find all pairs of integers $(n,k)$ that satisfy $(n+1)^k - 1 = n!$

Tags: number-theory

Find all pairs of integers $(n,k)$  that satisfy $(n+1)^k - 1 = n!$

It is easy to see that (1,1) and (2,1) are solutions by inspection,  but how do we prove that these are the only solutions? After sometime, I also saw that $(4,2)$ was also a solution, as it wasn't so obvious.

I was thinking that maybe $n! + 1$ cannot be a perfect power of a number? Though I also can't prove it. I also tried binomial theorem but still cant see anything.

Comment: $4!+1=5^2$, $5!+1=11^2$.

Comment: @lulu can we find relation between $a,b$ where $a!+1=b^2$?

Comment: @Fawad  Maybe...we also have $7!+1=71^2$, but there are no other examples for $a≤200$.

Comment: @Fawad  Turns out that it is an open problem, conjectured that the three examples I wrote out are all of them.  [Brocard's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem).